# Django template filters

Tags: django

Which filter should i use in django templates in order to display my text in the way it was entered including all the spaces and  even alignments(whether it's Left, Right etc) For eg: I want to add some description about a title and i want it to be in this form:

```
"My my, 2018 is going by so quickly! 

Maybe it went by fast because we were too busy loading up on all kinds of yummy food at all the new restaurants that opened up.
                    As usual, we took the liberty of curating a list of eateries that we think                      you should not keep waiting.


So, without much further adieu, there’s your Culinary Bucket List For The Rest Of 2018".
```

Currently my title description is set in this format : {{value:Linebreaks}}

Answer (score -1):

Use the inbuilt {{value | safe}}

Comment: . This filter is  keeping all the description lines in one paragraph and not taking the spaces and alignment. I want the filter to take all the spaces and alignment too .

Comment: Then you are not saving them as paragraphs if they do not have tags ? It does not mean the filter is not doing its work. Add <p>, \t and other tags to your text.